# Google Maps API Error: "initMap is not a function"

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I'm getting the Google Maps API Error: `initMap is not a function`. The weird thing is, that my map was working fine on my local testing, then I uploaded it to my site and got the error. Now it's not working on my local machine either. What is going on?

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="map"
             class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" 
             style="width:101%;height:400px;background:yellow">
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

---

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function myMap() {
        var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(40.488158, -85.615340);
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
        var mapOptions = {
            center: myCenter,
            zoom: 18
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myCenter,
            icon: 'img/smally.png',
            animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
        });

        marker.setMap(map);
    }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=myMap"></script>
```

Comment: where is your `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=myMap"
    async defer></script>` API KEY?

Comment: w3 schools said you only need that if you plan on getting heavy traffic, which I don't. Is that the problem? @rizkidprast

Comment: try to check this one [https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)

Comment: @RizkiDPrast Ok I'm using one now, still have the error though.

Comment: You're right, don't have to use `api key` for low traffic/ testing. please check the answer below

Answer (score 1):

Try to give `async=""` attribute as well like this. it works:

```js
function myMap() {
  var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(40.488158, -85.615340);
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
  var mapOptions = {
    center: myCenter,
    zoom: 18
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCenter,
    icon: 'img/smally.png',
    animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
  });

  marker.setMap(map);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=myMap" async="" defer=""></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="map" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" style="width:101%;height:400px;background:yellow">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```